# How do i refactor one JSON array into other format in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, arrays

I have a **JSON** array like this,

```
JSONArray content=
"[
{"+"\"pageid\":\"19\","+"\"company\":"+"\"C1\","+"\"pageview\":"+"\"10\","+"\"visitfreq\":"+"\"2\"},{"+"\"pageid\":\"19\","+"\"company\":"+"\"C2\","+"\"pageview\":"+"\"20\","+"\"visitfreq\":"+"\"4\"},{"+"\"pageid\":\"200\","+"\"company\":"+"\"C3\","+"\"pageview\":"+"\"30\","+"\"visitfreq\":"+"\"3\"}
]";
```

Code for JSONArray:

```
JSONObject jObj1 = new JSONObject();
jObj1.put("pageid", "19");
jObj1.put("company", "C1");
jObj1.put("pageview", "10");
jObj1.put("visitfreq", "2");

JSONObject jObj2 = new JSONObject();
jObj2.put("pageid", "19");
jObj2.put("company", "C2");
jObj2.put("pageview", "20");
jObj2.put("visitfreq", "4");

JSONObject jObj3 = new JSONObject();
jObj3.put("pageid", "200");
jObj3.put("company", "C3");
jObj3.put("pageview", "30");
jObj3.put("visitfreq", "3");

JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray();
jArr.put(jObj1);
jArr.put(jObj2);
jArr.put(jObj3);
```

[Visual representation:](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
[
    {
        "company": "C1",
        "visitfreq": "2",
        "pageview": "10",
        "pageid": "19"
    },
    {
        "company": "C2",
        "visitfreq": "4",
        "pageview": "20",
        "pageid": "19"
    },
    {
        "company": "C3",
        "visitfreq": "3",
        "pageview": "30",
        "pageid": "200"
    }
]
```

I have worked on it to get an out put like below

the out put like this

```
[{pageid},[{rest of details}] ,{pageid},[{rest of details}] ]
```

if same pageid occur more than once
it should be like this

```
[{pageid},[{rest of details1},{rest of details2},.. ],{pageid},[{rest of details}] ]
```

Comment: Uh, that's bogus code - a String (and that is not even a valid string literal) cannot be assigned to JSONArray. (Even if it could be, don't build JSON by-hand!) If the goal is just to show JSON, then show that actual JSON and not some mashup code; or at least show the real code used to generate the JSON/JSONArray.

Comment: what i need is from the input json array,in the input json array, if amore than one object contains same page id, that should be refactored in  way that in the output json  array only one pageid and corresponding to that other details in all objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to create a `Map` that maps `pageid : [{rest of details1},{rest of details2},.. ]`.

Once you have that `Map`, you can transform it into your desired output.
Here is the code that will take your `JSONArray` (the one in the code above) and turn it into `Map<String, JSONArray>`.

```
public Map<String, JSONArray> getJsonArrayAsMapOnPageId(JSONArray inputArr) throws JSONException {
    //Map holding pageid : [{company:"",pageview:"",visitfreq:""}, ... , ...] mappings
    Map<String, JSONArray> idMap = new HashMap<String, JSONArray>();

    for (int i=0; i < inputArr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject inputObj = inputArr.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = inputObj.getString("pageid");

        JSONArray jObjList;
        if (idMap.containsKey(id)) {
            //append to existing list in the Map
            jObjList = idMap.get(id);
        } else {
            //create new list
            jObjList = new JSONArray();
        }

        JSONObject newJsonObj = new JSONObject();
        newJsonObj.put("company", inputObj.get("company"));
        newJsonObj.put("pageview", inputObj.get("pageview"));
        newJsonObj.put("visitfreq", inputObj.get("visitfreq"));

        jObjList.put(newJsonObj);

        idMap.put(id, jObjList);
    }

    return idMap;
}
```

Here is what it'll look like:

```
System.out.println("Map looks like:\n" + pageidMap);
```

Here is what I got:

```
{
    200=[
        {
            "company": "C3",
            "visitfreq": "3",
            "pageview": "30"
        }
    ],
    19=[
        {
            "company": "C1",
            "visitfreq": "2",
            "pageview": "10"
        },
        {
            "company": "C2",
            "visitfreq": "4",
            "pageview": "20"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not sure exactly in what form (Object, print to output, etc) you want this output to be in, so you can do the final bit of transforming this `Map<String, JSONArray>` into `[{pageid},[{rest of details1},{rest of details2},.. ],{pageid},[{rest of details}] ]` without problems.